# Electron - link opens in new window

Tags: hyperlink, windows-10, electron

I have weird problem. In my app there is few links to other .html files. On Mac OS or Windows 7 links are open in the same window but in Windows 10 they open in new window. I don't have idea what is going on... Maybe you know?
Link looks like (there is nothing different):

```
<a href="page.html?id={{ id }}">Some link</a>
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure whats going on in your app to open new windows, so this doesn't get to the cause of your problem.

However, assuming your windows are being created by a rogue window.open call (or a target="_blank") you could block new-window events and load in your win like the following:

```
win.webContents.on('new-window', (event, url) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    win.loadURL(url)
})
```

See [more details here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#event-new-window)

Comment: `The signature '(event: "new-window",....'main.webContents.on' is deprecated`

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue with an Electron / Vue.js app running on a touch-screen Linux device, where touching a link would sometimes open it in a new window. Jann3's answer works, but has the effect of reloading the Vue app which introduces a lot of lag.

I found an Electron workaround by simply emitting a message from Electron's main process to the renderer process, in this case using Vue's router. The same logic should be applicable whatever you're using in the renderer process:

Electron main process:

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
  ...
})

win.webContents.on('new-window', (event, url) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  win.webContents.send('blocked-new-window', url)
})
```

Vue router.js:

```
require('electron').ipcRenderer.on('blocked-new-window', (event, url) => {
   router.push({path: url.split('#/')[1] || '/'})
})
```

Here is more on sending messages between the Main and Renderer processes: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-arg1-arg2-

Answer (score 1):

This has since been removed from Electron see:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#planned-breaking-api-changes-220.

You are now ment to use https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssetwindowopenhandlerhandler.

```js
mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler((details) => {
  return { action: 'deny' }
});
```